# My EV3 program will not run despite clicking on the program from the brick

Tags: ev3

This is a new EV3 Education Core Set. I have made a simple move forward command using the Lego Mindstorm EV3 Students Edition and downloaded it into the EV3 brick.  However when I press the program in the brick, nothing happens, not even a loading screen. When connected to the computer and the program is there, I just can't run it. How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is the EV3 connected to your computer? Do you hear the sound on the EV3 when the download is done? Can you share a screenshot of your program?

Comment: Hello I have clarified your question, it is connected and there is a sound.

Comment: Without seeing your program, I can only guess, but if there are no blocks that wait for something to happen before continuing, the program will stop right away. For example if your program only has a Motor On block, it will seem as if nothing happens because this block does not wait before continuing to the next block. If there is no next block, the program ends.

Answer (score 2):

You said that you did a simple move forward command. Is that the only thing you did? If so, then basically the program sees your "move forwards" and starts up the motors. It moves on to the next brick- but that's the end. If there are no bricks left, it terminates the program (stopping everything: including the motors). This all happens within milliseconds, so the motor doesn't even have a chance to start moving, and to you, it appears as if the program didn't do anything.

td;lr to fix this just make your program wait before ending. Like, "wait until <touch sensor [pressed]>" or "wait (5) seconds".

Answer (score -1):

I don't own the EV3, so unfortunately I can't help you with first-hand experience.  Here is a link to the LEGO site containing videos with everything you should need to know to get started.

[Getting Started with LEGO® MINDSTORMS® Education EV3](https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/mindstorms-ev3/getting-started)

Based on my experience with Mindstorms NXT, if you are sure the program is done correctly then make sure you chose the correct ports that your motors are plugged into.